# Uniswap v3 offline price calculation

Tags: ether, uniswap, uniswapv3

Is there an off-chain way to calculate `amountOut` for a pool, for any number of tokens in? I know I can do a RPC call, but I want to try a large amount of prices and that is inefficient. I would rather query the necessary pool data once, and then do the computation offline.

Is there a way to do that?